# CSS style.display not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following JavaScript function to display/hide a table row based on a listbox selection.

```
function clock_Type(id) {
    var clockSource = document.getElementById("clockSource");
    var clockType = document.getElementById("clockType");

    if(id == "1") {
        if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
            clockType.style.display = "inline";
            clockSource.style.display = "inline";
        } else {
            clockType.style.display = "table-row";
            clockSource.style.display = "table-row";
        }
    } else {
        clockType.style.display = "none";
        clockSource.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Following is the listbox.

```
<select id="clck" name="clock" class="selectStyle" style="width: 155px;" onchange="clock_Type(this.value)">
    <option value="0">Disabled</option>
    <option value="1">Enabled</option>
</select>
```

This is working fine on the listbox onchange event.  i.e. the table row is getting hidden and displayed.  But when I try to call the JS function clock_Type() from another function, as shown below, the table row is not getting displayed.

```
function foo() {
   clock_Type(1);
}
```

When I traced the code the execution reaches the following section for FireFox

```
clockType.style.display = "table-row";
clockSource.style.display = "table-row";
```

But the table row is not getting displayed.  Any idea what could be the issue here.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could it be that you're calling the function before the DOM is fully loaded? Also, although it's not the problem here, you should call the function with a string, not an integer (`clock_Type("1");`).

Comment: @Max — it seems unlikely, it is coming from an onchange event.

Comment: @David: it's not clear whether that is the case: "...when I try to call the JS function clock_Type() from another function...".

Comment: @Max, David: Thanks for looking into this issue.  I had tried string too in the function call.  But as I mentioned, the execution reaches the following lines of code in FF.

clockType.style.display = "table-row";
clockSource.style.display = "table-row";

But I cannot see the style change in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Set the display to an empty string instead of specifying "table-row" or "inline".  This will give the elements a default display, so unless they are specified `display:none;` in a stylesheet the user agent will negotiate the proper display.

```
clockType.style.display = "";
clockSource.style.display = "";
```

This also eliminates the need to execute a browser check which is not good practice.

**EDIT:**

I misunderstood your question before. However, I tested your code [here](http://jsbin.com/adija3/edit) and it seems to work fine (tested in FF 3.5.3, Chrome 4, IE8).

Comment: @Joel: Thanks for answering.  Let me give you more information on what I'm trying to do.  I have a select box (clock) on a page along with other form elements.  It has values 'Enabled' and 'Disabled'.  When the value is 'Enabled', I have to display two tables rows (clockType & clockSource) and when the value is 'Disabled' these rows should be hidden.  As I mentioned, this is working fine on onChange of the clock select box.  But when I try to call the JS function clock_Type() from another function, the style change is not reflected.

Comment: The need for calling clock_Type() from another function is that I need to populate the form fields with values from the database.  So after I populate the clock select box, I need to hide/display the clockType & clockSource table rows based on the Clock value i.e enabled/disabled.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Does #clockType and #clockSource elements have css class that sets display style? In this case I'd tried to remove it and set display style inline.

Comment: @Yaroslav: There is no css class for #clockType and #clockSource elements.